# "shut down lanes" vs. "close lanes" Are there any differences between them?

Tags: paraphrasing

News Report:

> "..which means all eastbound lanes of Interstate 70, shut down for
>   roadwork, will remain closed until Monday."

I think, the news report means "The eastbound lanes of Interstate 70 are closed now.", but other people say it doesn't.

In this case, who is right?

One more question:

> "The project will continue 'until' Monday."

Does this sentence mean "The project will be completed 'on' Monday." or "The project will be completed 'before' Monday."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference between using *shut down* and *closed* in those sentences. Both sentences still mean that the eastbound lanes are not passable.

> The project will continue until Monday

Means that the project will be completed on Monday.